# SyntaxError: Unexpected token r in JSON at position 38

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I was unexpected token r in JSON at position 38 for this code.

```
var object = JSON.parse('{"isFaceboook" : true,"redirectUrl" : redUrl,"facebookId" : id}');
```

redUrl and id are initialized and they are strings...

Comment: Well what is `redUrl` supposed to mean? That's the error, as `redUrl` is not a JSON keyword. JavaScript is not going to paste the values of those variables into your string. And what's the point anyway? Why not just create an object directly?

Comment: where from this data coming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no point to making a JSON string and parsing it:

```
var object = {
  isFacebook: true,
  redirectUrl: redUrl,
  facebookId: id
};
```

will work.

Answer (score 1):

Your variables will need to be stringified as well before it can be parsed.

Something like: '{"isFacebook":true,"redirectUrl":"redUrl","facebookId":4}'